# Node.js - execFile throws spawn UNKNOWN

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, exec, spawn

I am trying to spawn a service created with pyInstaller from an electron application. I am using the following code for that:

```
return new Promise((reject, resolve)=>{
var exec = require('child_process').execFile;
    exec(path.join(install_path, 'myService.exe'), ['--startup=auto', 'install'], function(err, data) { 
        if(err) {            
            reject(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log(data.toString()); 
        exec(path.join(install_path, 'myService.exe'), ['start'], function(err, data){
            if(err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            resolve(data.toString());
        })                      
    }); 
}
```

Unfortunately, this throws an

> Uncaught Error: spawn UNKNOWN

on a testing system, which does not have node installed and is running Windows 10 x64. On my machine it is working fine. 
Does anyone have tips how I could investigate this further? I am especially curious how this error is uncaught, because the callback functions obviously contain simple error handling.

Comment: Just a heads up, when you get an error don't continue.. eg.  `if(err) console.error(err)` will continue the rest of your code..  try `if(err) { console.error(err); return; }` or shorter `if(err) return console.error(err)`

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of that. I left out the `reject(err)` because I thought this would make the code simpler to understand and it's definitely not a mistake that has anything to do with promises ;)

Comment: There is no promises here,.. so yes, leaving out `reject(err)` is totally understandable.. :)

Comment: Now that you have updated you question to use Promises, not sure why.. But anyway,  `if(err) reject(err)`  Your doing it again,.. don't continue when you get an error, otherwise the error that's reported might not be the one you need.  Again, do .. `if (err) { reject(err); return; }` or shorter -> `if (err) return reject(err)`..  Or another popular one `if (err) reject(err); else { rest.... }`

Comment: Yeah that's what happens when you edit code without thinking about it too much^^

Comment: Ok, from the calling side how are you handling the error?.  Are you then catching the error further down the line.  eg.. `execute().catch(function (e) { console.error(e); })`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after I built in better error handling thanks to Keiths help and rebuilt the project, the testers could not reproduce the issue anymore. I am still not sure if that actually fixed the problem or if the testers pulled an old version the last time.
Anyway, this is solved.